# Android Studio "view bitmap" in debug mode does't show the bitmap

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap

Don't know why I receive this message while I'm trying to view the bitmap stored in my variable.

[image]

> "Unexpected error: Image Buffer is not an array"

I have always been able to view the image correctly

**INFO:**
Android Studio 3.2.1

Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 9, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.11.6

**EDIT 1:**
I'm debugging on a Xiaomi mi6, It seems to be a problem linked with developer option on MIUI 10 because on the android studio emulator and on my mi3 MIUI 8 everything works well

Comment: Same here, Android Studio 3.3 RC2 with MI8 MIUI 10

Comment: same problem, and use MI8

Comment: any solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved!

Seems to be a problem related to android 8 and MIUI 10, I upgraded my Xiaomi Mi6 to Android 9 and everything is working again.

ROM: "xiaomi.eu_multi_MI6_9.6.5_v10-9"